# EmberJS - adding some template in separated file

Tags: ember.js

I'm a newbie yet on EmberJS, started to learn a week ago. Well, I have some .html file named **contactsTemplate.html** that is a template what I want to use. Something like this below:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contacts">
    <h2>My Contact List</h2>

    {{#each contact in contactList}}
        {{contact.name}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Great. I have a **index.html** file that contains an `{{outlet}}` expression. It means that every new content will be loaded into this space, right?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>My Application</h1>

    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Ok... To manage this template named application, I've created a Controller object.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    ...
});
```

Same to contacts template:

```
App.ContactsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    contactList: []
});
```

I've created  two routes to manage this transition between pages:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("index", "/");
    this.route("contacts", "/contacts");
});
```

My doubt is:

1. How can I associate this separated files to a route? I mean, when I call on browser **http://mysite.com/** the index.html file should be loaded. When I call **http://mysite.com/#/contacts** the contactsTemplate.html should be loaded.

Sorry for the long text, and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default each declared `this.route(routeName)` in Router map, will have a `[routeName]Controller`, `[routeName]Route`, and expect a `[routeName]` template, following these conventions described in http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/.

To change from one route to other, you can use:

- Inside of a controller `this.transitionToRoute(routeName)`
- Inside of a route `this.transitionTo(routeName)`
- Inside of a template {{#link-to "routeName" }}My route{{/link-to}}

You can find more information in the routing guide http://emberjs.com/guides/routing

I hope it helps

Comment: Perfect, Márcio! It's all that I need.